# Cannot obtain cursor from ndb query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cursors

I need to query the datastore using cursors (I need cursors because the task may not finish within then 10 minute period). So far I have not been able to obtain a valid cursor using with either fetch_page or Query.iter(). In both cases, when I use the produced cursor, I get a

> BadRequestError: cursor position is outside the range of the original
>   query

Here is the query

```
qry = entity_type.query(ndb.AND(entity_type.application == "my_app",
                                ndb.OR(entity_type.status == 1,
                                       ndb.AND(entity_type.status == 0,
                                               entity_type.date >= start_date,
                                               entity_type.date < end_date))))

qry = qry.order(entity_type.date, entity_type._key)
```

Notice that I 'm filtering with the ndb.OR and I 'm also sorting the query on the model's key as described on the on-line documentation.

The code that runs the query is quite straightforward

```
cursor = None
has_more = True
while has_more:       
    entities, cursor, more = qry.fetch_page(500,
                                            start_cursor=cursor,
                                            use_cache=False,
                                            use_memcache=False)
    # process the retrieved entities
    has_more  = cursor and more
```

The first loop works ok (cursor is None). On the second loop (cursor is initialized), I get the error. I have also tried doing this with iterators:

```
cursor = None
has_more = True
while has_more:
    q_options = {"use_cache": False,
                 "use_memcache": False,
                 "produce_cursors": True}
    if cursor is not None:
        q_options["start_cursor"] = cursor

    q_iter = qry.iter(**q_options)
    entities = []
    for e in q_iter:
        entities.append(e)
        if len(entities) == 500:
            break

    more = q_iter.has_next()
    if more:
        cursor = q_iter.cursor_after()

    # process the retrieved entities
    has_more = cursor and more
```

and I see the same behavior. I am currently working on breaking the ndb.OR to two separate queries. Yet I 'm wondering whether I am misusing the ndb API or is it something else?

-- update --
Here is the trace from the error

```
W 05:00:09.171 suspended generator run_to_queue(query.py:938) raised BadRequestError(cursor position is outside the range of the original query)
W 05:00:09.762 suspended generator run_to_queue(query.py:1946) raised BadRequestError(cursor position is outside the range of the original query)
W 05:00:09.762 suspended generator run_to_queue(query.py:931) raised BadRequestError(cursor position is outside the range of the original query)
W 05:00:09.762 suspended generator helper(context.py:876) raised BadRequestError(cursor position is outside the range of the original query)
W 05:00:09.762 suspended generator has_next_async(query.py:1745) raised BadRequestError(cursor position is outside the range of the original query)
W 05:00:09.777 suspended generator _fetch_page_async(query.py:1349) raised BadRequestError(cursor position is outside the range of the original query)
E 05:00:09.777 cursor position is outside the range of the original query
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    [... some of my classes ...]
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/utils.py", line 142, in positional_wrapper
      return wrapped(*args, **kwds)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1331, in fetch_page
      return self.fetch_page_async(page_size, **q_options).get_result()
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 325, in get_result
      self.check_success()
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along
      value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1349, in _fetch_page_async
      while (yield it.has_next_async()):
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along
      value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1745, in has_next_async
      yield self._fut
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 876, in helper
      batch, i, ent = yield inq.getq()
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 931, in run_to_queue
      yield multiquery.run_to_queue(queue, conn, options=options)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along
      value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1946, in run_to_queue
      thing = yield subit.getq()
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 938, in run_to_queue
      batch = yield rpc
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 454, in _on_rpc_completion
      result = rpc.get_result()
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
      return self.__get_result_hook(self)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2973, in __query_result_hook
      self._batch_shared.conn.check_rpc_success(rpc)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1342, in check_rpc_success
      raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
  BadRequestError: cursor position is outside the range of the original query
W 05:00:10.040 Found 1 RPC request(s) without matching response (presumably due to timeouts or other errors)
```

Comment: What error? Give us tracelog please.

Comment: The AND/OR/AND nesting makes it complex to reason about the query and cursor, but I suspect it would work if you **just** ordered by key (rather than by date then key).  Is that the case?  If so, and you do need the date ordering, then splitting the query (and cursors) may indeed be the only way out.

Comment: I also added the tracelog if that helps

Comment: @Christos did you take a second to check Alex Martelli's suggestions? Running the query JUST ordered by key? I do believe this will help your issue. It will not give exactly what you want, but it will help figure out how your issue can be fixed :)